# SUPEE6788 APPSEC-1063 SQL Injection

Tags: magento-1.9, supee-6788, regex

I've been looking around and haven't found any definitive heuristics to detect whether or not a code-base is affected, so I've resorted to performing a recursive file scan that matches a list of regular expressions.

This has been met with varying success, as my regex powers are limited and I am getting a boatload of false-positives.

According to the technical release notes the following patterns are invalid:

```
$collection->addFieldToFilter('`field`', array('eq'=>3)); 

$collection->addFieldToFilter('(field1-field2)', array('eq'=>3));
```

---

Here is what I have thus far:

```
~("|')[^'|^"]*(\=|\-|\<|\>|\>|\!).+("|')~
~addFieldToFilter\(("|'){\$~
~addFieldToFilter\(("|')\s+`~
```

How can I improve these expressions to produce fewer false-positives?

Answer (score 1):

The (very helpful) [supee-6788-toolbox](https://github.com/rhoerr/supee-6788-toolbox/blob/master/fixSUPEE6788.php) performs something to this effect.  It looks like the regex that they're using is:

```
'/addFieldToFilter\(\s*[\'"]?[\`\(]/i'
```

Although it does have a disclaimer that it may produce false positives as well as false negatives (overlooking some occurances).

Comment: That expression doesn't check for "{$variable}" conditions.  Think this question should be moved to a more regex-oriented board?  I'm reaching out to the the regex gods on this one.

Comment: The `check()` function in the script looks to be used to inspect for variables, but it's used to scan SQL resultsets.  Do you plan to use your regex's on your code and/or database?

Comment: Right now I'm just scanning the code-base.  We're using a large third party module and I've currently found 3 spots where the front-end is subject to a SQL error from the expressions in my question.  The trouble is, for every 1 positive, I'm checking out 50 negatives.

Comment: sounds like my experience.  I've been trying to think of a clever way to eat this elephant, but in the meantime I've just been whittling away at it one nibble at a time.  On the bright side Magento is (finally) issuing security patches&ndash;these holes aren't new.